# How to manually subscribe apollo client subscription

Tags: javascript, reactjs, apollo-client

I hope you guys are doing well!

I'm trying to use apollo graphqQL subscription.

I used **useSubscription** and It works fine. But I don't want to use hook because it subscribes automatically on the component mount. I don't need to subscribe to the query for the whole time. I just wanna subscribe to it only for a specific event. for now, I am subscribing by a button onClick event.

So I tied this approach:

```
APIClient.subscribe({
        query: BULK_CREATE_PROCESS_DETAILS,
        variables: {
          id: {
            userId: id,
          },
        },
      }).subscribe((data) =>{
        console.log(data)
      });
```

but when I try to subscribe, I get an error.

[image]

Here is my subscription query:

```
gql(`
  subscription bulkCreateProcessDetails(
    $id: BulkShippingDetailsSubscriptionInput!
  ) {
    bulkCreateProcessDetails(id: $id) {
      reason
      orderNumber
    }
  }
`);
```

Packages Versions:

```
"react": "^18.1.0",
"@apollo/client": "^3.6.2",
"graphql": "^16.5.0",
"graphql-ws": "^5.11.2",
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by assigning the value to a new variable.

```
const subscriptionObserver = APIClient.subscribe({
        query: BULK_CREATE_PROCESS_DETAILS,
        variables: {
          id: {
            userId: id,
          },
        },
      }).subscribe((data) => {
        console.log(data);
      });
    
      // setSubscriptionObserver is a useState function for cleanup the subscription
    
      setSubscriptionObserver(subscriptionObserver);
```

It worked fine for me.

> Don't forget to unsubscribe from the subscription.